# Why is (1-t)^2 == (t-1)^2 in SageMath?

Tags: math, sage

This is really odd, not much to say about it.

```
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ SageMath version 8.5, Release Date: 2018-12-22                     │
│ Using Python 2.7.15. Type "help()" for help.                       │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

[image: -t]

Comment: Why would it not be true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That statement is actually true across the real and complex numbers. If t = 5, for example, then (1 - 5) ^ 2 == (5 - 1) ^ 2 is true.

(Also this question might be right on the edge of "off-topic" for Stack Overflow seeing as how it's really more a math question and not a programming question, but I guess Sage is a library as well... :-) )

Comment: I just checked by hand and I feel really dumb. Thanks

Comment: Edited to make you feel better…you might have found a bug. :-)

Comment: mathematically it makes sense so perhaps it's shouldn't be considered a bug. But it really confuses me. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, nope—I convinced myself it works in the complex plane too…retracted my edit. Agreed that it makes you at least blink twice though.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3079007/why-is-1-t2-t-12-in-sagemath?noredirect=1#comment6347935_3079007

Comment: -(a-b) = -a+b = b-a.  That's something you should have in your head ready to go.